# How to use active directory authentication with NEST/Elasticsearch.net

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am aware of how to use basic authentication on the connectionsettings using NEST. But if I wanted to use active directory/ldap authentication, how will I make the connection? Is there any sample available?

Is it sample as passing id/pwd when we use basic authentication?

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(mEsQuerySource.Url));
settings.BasicAuthentication("user", "plain text password");
mClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that kind of functionality is built into X-Pack.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/active-directory-realm.html

Comment: @askids. Mike Michaels is correct, this is supported with X-Pack Security.

Comment: @RussCam i am aware that its available with X-pack security and couple of other plugins. But if I have enabled ldap authentication, then when connecting via NEST client, how do I pass the credentials. Is it same as passing the id/pwd as in Basic Authentication?